# How to quit my app if there is an uncaught exception?

Tags: android, activity-finish, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I want to quit my app if there is an uncaught exception. For that I'm using `System.exit(10)` and `Process.killProcess`(I know this is not a good practice to call these methods). My code is the following:

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    String Tag;
    Context myContext;
    public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, String TAG) {
        Tag = TAG;
        myContext = context;
    }  

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        Logger.appendErrorLog(sw.toString(), Tag);
        System.exit(10);
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

But the problem with this code is, after calling the exit method, my application again restarts(Home activity of app starts). I don't want my app to start again once exception comes. To resolve this issue I tried one more way:

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    String Tag;
    Context myContext;
    public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, String TAG) {
        Tag = TAG;
        myContext = context;
    }  

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        Logger.appendErrorLog(sw.toString(), Tag);
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

After this I'm calling finish in my `HomeActivity`. After running this code my application is not at all quitting and I'm getting a black screen

How can I kill the application either by using exit method or by finishing all activities?

Comment: "After running this code my application is not at all quitting and I'm getting a black screen" -- and when you used tools like Hierarchy View to determine what activity of yours is on the screen at this point, what did you learn?

Comment: call this method it will exit the application finish();